# QEMU starts blinking with custom boot loader in x86

Tags: x86, nasm, bootloader, osdev, protected-mode

I'm writing my own boot loader for i386 in NASM for education purposes. But when I'm running qemu with this it starts blinking and do anything but what I want. Here's my code:

```
; defs.asm
%define STACK_SEGMENT_REAL_MODE 0x9000
%define STACK_SEGMENT_PROT_MODE 0xFFFFFFFE
```

```
; head.asm
[bits 16]
[org 0x7C00]

%include "defs.asm"

start:
    cli

    xor ax, ax ; AX = 0
    mov ds, ax ; DS = 0
    mov es, ax ; ES = 0
    mov ss, ax ; SS = 0

    mov esp, STACK_SEGMENT_REAL_MODE
    mov ebp, esp

    sti

    call switch_real_to_prot

    ; at this point interrupts are diabled
  ; infinite loop
    jmp $

%include "protection.asm"

times 510-($-$$) db 0

db 0x55
db 0xAA
```

```
; protection.asm
; ----------------- Global Descriptor Table -----------------
;
;        Segment Descriptor
; 31              23               15                7               0
; +---------------+-+-+-+----------+-+-----+-+-----+-+---------------+
; |               | | |A|          | |     | |     | |               |
; |  BASE 31..24  |G|X|V|  LIMIT   |P| DPL |1| TYPE|A|  BASE 21..16  |
; |               | | |L|  19..16  | |     | |     | |               |
; +---------------+-+-+-+----------+-+-----+-+-----+-+---------------+
; |                                |                                 |
; |       SEGMENT BASE 15..0       |      SEGMENT LIMIT 15..0        |
; |                                |                                 |
; +--------------------------------+---------------------------------+

%include "defs.asm"

%define GDT_CS_PROT 0x08
%define GDT_DS_PROT 0x10

gdt:
    ; NULL Segment Descriptor
    dq 0

    ; Code Segment Descriptor
    ;
    ; BASE = 0x00000000
    ; LIMIT = 0xFFFFF (4GB), 4KiB GRANULARITY,
    ; PRESENT TYPE = 32 bit, EXECUTE/READ, DPL = 0
    dw 0xFFFF
    dw 0
    db 0
    db 0x9A
    db 0xCF
    db 0

    ; Data Segment Descriptor
    ;
    ; BASE = 0x00000000
    ; LIMIT = 0xFFFFF (4GB), 4KiB GRANULARITY,
    ; PRESENT TYPE = 32 bit, READ/WRITE, DPL = 0
    dw 0xFFFF
    dw 0
    db 0
    db 0x92
    db 0xCF
    db 0
gdt_end:

gdt_desc:          ;   Func  | Bits
                   ; --------+------
    db gdt_end - gdt ; Limit   | 0-15
    dw gdt           ; Address | 16-47

switch_real_to_prot:
    [bits 16]
    cli

    xor ax, ax
    mov ds, ax

    lgdt [gdt_desc]

    ; switch to protected mode
    mov eax, cr0
    or  eax, 1
    mov cr0, eax

    jmp GDT_CS_PROT:init_prot

[bits 32]
init_prot:
    ; Since this moment all data segment registers
    ; point to the same data segment in GDT:0x10
    mov ax, GDT_DS_PROT
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax

    ; move return address to the real stack
    mov eax, [esp]
    mov [STACK_SEGMENT_REAL_MODE], eax

    ; get protected mode stack
    mov eax, [STACK_SEGMENT_PROT_MODE]
    mov esp, eax
    mov ebp, eax

    ; put the return address to the correct stack
    mov eax, [STACK_SEGMENT_REAL_MODE]
    mov [esp], eax

    xor eax, eax

    ret
```

I build it using `nasm`:

```bash
$ nasm -f bin head.asm -o boot
```

and run qemu like:

```bash
$ qemu-system-i386 boot
```

and then I see something weird. Can anybody explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your `gdt_desc` is wrong. It should be `gdt_desc:`  `dw gdt_end - gdt -1`  `dd gdt` (changed from `db` to `dw` and `dw` to `dd` as well as subtracting one from the size. Your protected mode stack is near the top of memory where the BIOS likely resides so that will cause problems. Change `STACK_SEGMENT_PROT_MODE` to something like `%define STACK_SEGMENT_PROT_MODE 0x90000` . The other problem is you copy the real mode return address to the protected mode stack incorrectly. You might have been going for something like https://pastebin.com/HbPMcDBt .

Comment: In head.asm you will also have to put a `bits 32` after `call switch_real_to_prot` since you will be returning in 32-bit protected mode (not 16-bit mode).

Comment: @MichaelPetch, thanks, that works, but why the original approach to copy return address does not work fine, tbh, I took it from GRUB from protcseg function (https://github.com/coreos/grub/blob/2.02-coreos/grub-core/kern/i386/realmode.S#L166)?